# Apps are continuously getting crashed one after the other

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

My android phone (Motorola moto g) is behaving weird from few days. After successful boot of the phone, all the apps in the phone started crashing. I only see "unfortunately some-app is stopped working" message in the middle of the screen. I don't have any way other than to tap on "ok", doing this the same message appears again.

When I try to factory reset phone from boot menu, the phone reboots automatically. If I connect the phone to a computer using USB the device is not getting recognized by the computer.

I am not sure on how to solve this issue or factory reset the phone. Please let me know alternatives you have to solve this issue.

The screenshot of fastboot screen:

[image]

Comment: Can you boot into [tag:fastboot] mode? If yes, then setup prerequisites for fastboot in PC and execute `fastboot -w` or `fastboot erase cache` and `fastboot erase data` commands. This would cause data loss - virtually everything you created or moved into the internal storage of your phone. Let us know the results.

Comment: @Firelord I have access to fastmode commands, but the commands doesn't format the phone...

Comment: You're saying they were successfully executed and still the phone doesn't seem to be formatted? Is the bootloader unlocked?

Comment: @Firelord Bootloader seems unlocked

Comment: Jaguar, this may seem a bit of a hassle but can you post the screenshot of the window from which you successfully executed those commands? I'm interested in output of the commands. Also, when the device is in fastboot mode, what do you see on the screen of your device?

Comment: @Firelord added screenshot